# Validators in User Control Not Firing Using VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

I have a wizard control where each step contains a user control.

On each user control (or each step) I have validators, custom validators, required validators, etc. The issue I have is that I am having to write this application in VB.Net, which has been forced on me rather in C#. In the hosting page on its OnLoad event, I usually attach the event by using the usercontrol name.RequiredValidator += usercontrol name.RequiredValidator_Validate. However, in VB.Net I can't seem to do this!

I have tried using a C# to VB.net converter, but this didn't work either.

So, my question is this, how do you attach events in the hosting page from the user control in VB.Net????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have this control (pretend I added all the needed attributes):

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" />
```

In C#, you'd wire up an event like:

```
btn.Click += btn_Click;
```

In VB.Net, you'd wire it up like:

```
AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_Click
```

Just apply that to whatever event you are wiring up to.  For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx#Y0

Comment: Thanks, but can you confirm how this would work with usercontrols? Would it be AddHandler UserControlName.RequiredValidator, AddressOf UserControlName.RequiredValidator_Validate? Is this the right syntax?

Comment: The right of `AddressOf` is the name of your event handler that you would define in your code.

Comment: Hi. I gave it ago. The AddHandler was ok, but when I added the AddressOf for the event name it says that event name is not apart the object that I wish to wire up to. So, I tried adding the event name to my Interface, but this never worked. Any ideas???